# I'd like to see the difference between Answers and Questions when reviewing

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits I'd like to be able to see whether it's an edited question or an edited answer. Because edits to a question that appear to answer the question, or correct a bug that is the root of the problem, are considered bad and edits to an answer that improve of fix an answer are considered good.

Now I have to go to the answer or question under review to see what it is.

When reviewing "Low Quality Posts" you can see what you are reviewing:

[image: answer]

[image: question]

Comment: Come to think of it; this may need to be moved to the overall meta.

Comment: In First Posts, answers have an orange flash when they show up, and questions don't.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi, Talk about subtle. I thought the orange flash was just some kind of layout bug that appeared once in a while, but that I couldn't reproduce reliably so I didn't think it was worth reporting.

Comment: *Because edits to a question that appear to fix an issue are considered bad* Really?

Comment: @A.L I'll update the question

Answer (score 8):

Look for **asked ## mins ago** (for questions) or **answered ## mins ago** (for answers) text towards the bottom of the post (above the user flair).

When an edit is suggested on a question:

> [image]

When an edit is suggested on an answer:

> [image]

Other one is a subtle difference, hyperlink color of a question title is blue (#07c) whereas color of an answer title is gray (#555).

<sup>These colors are for Stack Overflow main.</sup>

Comment: Ah thanks I completely missed that. I thought I'd suggest it because when reviewing low quality post it does show whether it's an answer or a question.

Comment: @albertjan You may edit your current question and add screenshot/mockup of how it should look like to make it a proper _feature request_, so others can evaluate the usefulness of this proposed change. Currently it looks like a _support_ question as it says "I'd like to be able to see whether it's an edited question or an edited answer".

Comment: I'm used to writing feature requests this way, I automatically prepend "As a user " in my head. This makes it a feature request alla bdd. I will add the screenshots

Comment: The information is in light grey on white which is barely visible at the best of times. It should be one of the first things you see when reviewing suggested edits.